# Getting the Percent in the same table

Tags: mysql, sql

i'm having difficult time getting the percent on the same table.

i want to get the success rate per sub_group. success / total transaction * 100

```
STATUS,  GROUP,  SUB_GROUP
success,  2004, 80007022
success, 2004, 80007022
success, 2004, 80007022
success, 2004, 80007002
error, 2004, 80007002
error, 2004, 80007002
error, 2004, 80007002
error, 2004, 80007002
error, 2004, 80007002
error, 2004, 80007002
success, 2003, 80007007
success, 2003, 80007007
success, 2003, 80007007
success, 2003, 80007007
success, 2003, 80007007
success, 2003, 80007007
success, 2003, 80007007
success, 2003, 80007007
success, 2003, 80007007
success, 2003, 80007007
error, 2003, 80007007
error, 2003, 80007007
error, 2003, 80007007
```

Expected Results:

```
SUB_GROUP, Total, Success_Rate
80007022, 10, 40%
80007007, 13, 76.92%
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use conditional aggregation:

```
select sub_group, count(*),
       avg(status = 'Success') * 100
from t
group by sub_group;
```

This uses the MySQL shorthand that treats boolean expressions as integers in a numeric context, with "1" for true and "0" for false.  Hence, the `avg()` is calculating the percent of successes among the rows in each group.

Comment: That's a very simple and neat solution , nice .

Answer (score 0):

Use a `group by` query like

```
select SUB_GROUP,
sum(case when STATUS = 'success' then 1 else 0 end) as total,
count(STATUS) / sum(case when STATUS = 'success' then 1 else 0 end)* 100 as Success_Rate
from table1
group by SUB_GROUP
```

Answer (score 0):

select SUB_GROUP,
sum(case STATUS when 'success' then 1 else 0 end) as total,
(sum(case STATUS when 'success' then 1 else 0 end)* 100/count(*)) +'%' as Success_Rate
from table1

group by SUB_GROUP

Answer (score 0):

select SUB_GROUP, sum( if(STATUS='success', 1, 0) ) as total,
     (sum(if(STATUS='success', 1, 0) )*100/count(*)) +'%' as Success_Rate
 from tab
 group by SUB_GROUP